# How to clean nsurlsession downloadTask generate tmp File?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

If I create a DownloadTask by nsurlsession, there was a tmp file named like `'CFNetworkDownload_1vY41L.tmp'` in /Developer/tmp/ folder.

Then how to delete the tmp file when I delete downloadTask?

Moreover, I don't want to delete all tmp file because there are other downloadTask cache file.

Comment: Why you need to worry about those tmp files ? It will get deleted automatically

Comment: What is the `/Developer/tmp/` folder?  That's not part of the app bundle on iOS or OSX.

Comment: @Midhun MP Because of after delete half download Task, the diskSpace not free at once. And user will confuse.

Comment: @trojanfoe /Developer/tmp/ is in the iOS App sandbox inside.

Comment: That's news to me.

Answer (score 2):

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411511-downloadtask) says that the file will be deleted once the download block finishes, check **location** explanation. And yes it is deleted, at least in iOS 12, you have to move it before it completes, no need to free space.

Example:

```
let task = self.session.downloadTask(with: request) { [weak self] url, response, error in
   if let error = error {
      ...
    }

    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                fatalError("Couldn't get HTTP response")
    }

    if 200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode, let downloadedPath = url {
       // Move file in downloadedPath to a documents or other location
    }
}
```

downloadPath will have the location of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the file using [removeItemAtPath:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/removeItemAtPath:error:) method of `NSFileManager`

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"Your File Name"] error:NULL])
{
    NSLog(@"File deleted !!!");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"Couldn't delete the file !!!");
}
```

Comment: The keypoint is the 'CFNetworkDownload_1vY41L.tmp' name, and I don't know how to get it...